# Add UITextField on UIView programmatically

Tags: iphone, uiview, uitextfield

How to programmatically add `UITextField` on `UIView` in iPhone programming?

```
UITextField* text;
UIView* view = [[UIView alloc]init];

[view addSubview:???];
```

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Objective-C:

```
CGRect someRect = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 100.0, 30.0);
UITextField* text = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:someRect]; 
UIView* view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:someRect];

[view addSubview:text];
```

Swift:

```
let someFrame = CGRect(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, width: 100.0, height: 30.0)

let text = UITextField(frame: someFrame)
let view = UIView(frame: someFrame)
view.addSubview(text)
```

Comment: What are the frames?

Comment: @galactikuh what do you mean? Frames are rectangles in which your views will be placed.

Comment: if this is an important part of the answer, it seems like the creation of the frame should be included in your code.

Comment: Not much, but I added creating to the Obj-C part

Answer (score 250):

If you want one looking like the text field in Interface builder:

```
UITextField *textField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 200, 300, 40)];
textField.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyleRoundedRect;
textField.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:15];
textField.placeholder = @"enter text";
textField.autocorrectionType = UITextAutocorrectionTypeNo;
textField.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeDefault;
textField.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyDone;
textField.clearButtonMode = UITextFieldViewModeWhileEditing;
textField.contentVerticalAlignment = UIControlContentVerticalAlignmentCenter;    
textField.delegate = self;
[self.view addSubview:textField];
[textField release];
```

Comment: `contentVerticalAlignment` is the crucial element here

Comment: +1 @NathanielSymer : I spent 1 hour to figure that until I see your comment here... :) Thanks..

Comment: big thank to @ioshero this is really a good answer... IMHO I think should be marked as a correct answered. the fact you covered alot of the different parameters of the UITextField is just great. Once again, thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 3):

**In Swift 2.0:**

```
let sampleTextField = UITextField(frame: CGRectMake(20, 100, 300, 40))
sampleTextField.placeholder = "placeholderText"
sampleTextField.font = UIFont.systemFontOfSize(15)
sampleTextField.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyle.RoundedRect
sampleTextField.autocorrectionType = UITextAutocorrectionType.No
sampleTextField.keyboardType = UIKeyboardType.Default
sampleTextField.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyType.Done
sampleTextField.clearButtonMode = UITextFieldViewMode.WhileEditing;
sampleTextField.contentVerticalAlignment = UIControlContentVerticalAlignment.Center
sampleTextField.delegate = self
self.view.addSubview(sampleTextField)
```

**In Swift 3.0:**

```
let sampleTextField = UITextField(frame: CGRect(x: 20, y: 100, width: 300, height: 40))
sampleTextField.placeholder = "placeholderText"
sampleTextField.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 15)
sampleTextField.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyle.roundedRect
sampleTextField.autocorrectionType = UITextAutocorrectionType.no
sampleTextField.keyboardType = UIKeyboardType.default
sampleTextField.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyType.done
sampleTextField.clearButtonMode = UITextFieldViewMode.whileEditing;
sampleTextField.contentVerticalAlignment = UIControlContentVerticalAlignment.center
sampleTextField.delegate = self
self.view.addSubview(sampleTextField)
```

Answer (score 3):

```
UITextField *mycooltext=[[UITextField alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 70, 50, 50)];
mycooltext.text=@"I am cool";
[self.view addSubview:mycooltext];
```